# How to disable reverse portrait rotation?

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, xiaomi, miui, android-10

I have a rooted Xiaomi redmi note 7 with the latest stable Xiaomi.eu ROM (Android 10) I want to have back the standard Portrait and Landscape Rotation and remove the reversed portrait rotation from my phone entirely.

Comment: Hi, since [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/227090) is your previous question, consider completing the registration so that you won't lose access to your current account in the future to still be able to interact with your posts. That said, as I've mentioned the Xiaomi link on the previous question, looks like this needs a modification to the framework APK, which I can't guarantee the safety.

Comment: I didn't see your answer sorry.  What could go wrong with modifying the framework? I have no important data on my phone.

Comment: These are the hints: [1](https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/9-8-29-9-9-3-9-9-6-last-miui-10.52036/post-502463), [2](https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/9-8-29-9-9-3-9-9-6-last-miui-10.52036/post-502490), I'm not posting it as an answer since I can't test it and again, I can't guarantee the safety since modifying the system framework might brick the device, rendering it unusable. If you feel brave, then you can try it, and feel free to post it as an answer if it works. Best of luck.

Comment: If it carries the risk of bricking the phone then I won't do it. It looks like I'll have to change the ROM... I've been using Xiaomi Europe for a long time and they didn't have all rotation unlocked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: that rotation is cool, it will save your day when screen is broken

Comment: No it's not. It's annoying when you're lying on your side on the bed and  you want to keep switch between landscape and portrait.